Ensemble average under integral sign
Let's say there is some $v(t) = \int_0^t f(t) dt $. How can I take an ensemble average of this quantity?
Is $\langle v(t) \rangle = \int_0^t \langle f(t) \rangle dt$? How does the average goes inside the integral?
What if I had to evaluate $\langle v(t)^2 \rangle$? Is it equal to $\langle v(t)^2 \rangle= \int_0^t \int_0^t \langle f(t)f(t') \rangle dt dt' $?
Are these relations as written generally valid? Are there any derivation for these relations?
Edit: This question is written with respect to Brownian dynamics where $v(t)$ is given by the following equation:
$$ v(t) = e^{\frac{\zeta t}{m}}v(0)+\frac{1}{m}\int_0^t dt' e^{\frac{\zeta (t-t')}{m}} \eta(t')$$
$\eta(t)$ is a fluctuating force governed by $\langle \eta(t) \rangle = 0 \hspace{2mm} \langle \eta(t)\eta(t') \rangle = B\delta(t-t')$. The velocity is derived from Langevin equation:
$$ m\frac{dv}{dt} = -\zeta v+\eta(t)$$
How can I derive the mean-squared velocity ($\langle v(t)^2 \rangle$ averaged over the fluctuating force?

How are you defining an ensemble average? Which ensemble (micro, canonical or grand) are you even using, and over what constants/summation?

Have I satisfactorily addressed your question? I am looking to understand the derivation of the specific expressions and also the generality of the principle.

Maybe it's more obvious to someone more familiar in the field, but I still don't see what I'm asking for. How exactly is $\langle g(t)\rangle$ defined for some arbitrary quantity $g$?

You might ask your physics teacher.

In the standard notation of stochastic processes the answer boils down to the Fubini theorem for the product measure $d\mathbb P\otimes,dt,.$

Inserting the average inside the integral is indeed a valid move, at least in your context. In fact, you can reinterpret the stochastic process $v_t$, which is nothing else than one time-dependent random variable, as a collection of time-independent random variables, each variable corresponding to a time $t$ (this point of view can be associated to the ergodic hypothesis). Since the integral turns out to be a summation over infinitesimal intervals, the relation $\langle \int f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t \rangle = \int \langle f(t) \rangle \mathrm{d}t$ is actually the continuous analog of the property of linearity, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[\sum_i X_i] = \sum_i \mathbb{E}[X_i]$.
Now, in the case of your Brownian system, you can adopt two strategies. You can either compute it straighforwardly thanks to the aforementioned properties, i.e.
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\langle v(t)^2 \rangle 
   =& \displaystyle 
   \left\langle \left(e^{\zeta t/m}v_0 + \frac{1}{m} \int_0^t e^{\zeta(t-t')/m}\eta(t') \,\mathrm{d}t'\right)\left(e^{\zeta t/m}v_0 + \frac{1}{m} \int_0^t e^{\zeta(t-t'')/m}\eta(t'') \,\mathrm{d}t''\right) \right\rangle \\
   =& \displaystyle 
   e^{2\zeta t/m}v_0^2 
   + \frac{e^{\zeta t/m}}{m}v_0 \int_0^t e^{\zeta(t-t')/m}\langle\eta(t')\rangle \mathrm{d}t' 
   + \frac{e^{\zeta t/m}}{m}v_0 \int_0^t e^{\zeta(t-t'')/m}\langle\eta(t'')\rangle \mathrm{d}t'' \\
   & \displaystyle
   + \frac{1}{m^2} \int_0^t\mathrm{d}t' \int_0^t\mathrm{d}t'' \; e^{\zeta(2t-t'-t'')/m}\langle\eta(t')\eta(t'')\rangle \\
   =& \displaystyle
   e^{2\zeta t/m}v_0^2 + \frac{B}{m^2} \int_0^t\mathrm{d}t' \int_0^t\mathrm{d}t'' \; e^{\zeta(2t-t'-t'')/m}\delta(t'-t'') \\
   =& \displaystyle
   e^{2\zeta t/m}v_0^2 + \frac{B}{m^2} \int_0^t e^{2\zeta(t-t')/m} \,\mathrm{d}t' \\
   =& \displaystyle
   \frac{B}{2\zeta m} + \left(v_0^2 - \frac{B}{2\zeta m}\right) e^{2\zeta t/m} 
\end{array}
$$
since $\eta(t)$ has zero mean and is delta-correlated. But, alternatively, you can also start from the initial differential equation by writing
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}v^2 = 2v\dot{v} = -\frac{2\zeta}{m}v^2 + \frac{2\eta}{m}v,
$$
hence
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \langle v^2 \rangle = -\frac{2\zeta}{m} \langle v^2 \rangle,
$$
since $\eta$ and $v$ are decorrelated. Now, you face a simple ODE for $\langle v^2 \rangle$.
